# Ubuntu images showing very weird

Tags: drivers, graphics, 15.10

I posted a few days ago a similar post, someone asked me to do some codes on terminal, but no answer back, so I am posting again.

They also suggested to use another desktop, I tried all of them but no luck, the same resulsts.

The problem I am facing is since the last update, I have images, windows, titles and texts showing very weird.

I dont see this as a problem of the computer, (despite being quite old) as this problem only started after the upgrade from 15.4 to 15.10.

If anyone can help, here is the output...

*-display description: VGA compatible controller product: 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller vendor: Intel Corporation physical id: 2 bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0 version: 10 width: 32 bits clock: 33MHz capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom configuration: driver=i915 latency=0 resources: irq:27 memory:e1200000-e127ffff ioport:e000(size=8) memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e1000000-e10fffff – user193385 Oct 28 at 9:38

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I honestly do not know if this will help, but it may be worth a try.  You could install the oibaf drivers and see if this aids in fixing your problem.  The [launchpad page for oibaf](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) contains instructions for installing, and removing the drivers if required.